# TCP chat room in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, tcp, chat

I have recently started looking into networking with Python. I saw some tutorials about the socket library so I decided to give a "live chat room" idea a go. It works (on Windows, `os.system("cls")` may be problematic) but was just wanting to see how people could improve upon it

**server.py**

```
from socketserver import ThreadingTCPServer, BaseRequestHandler
from threading import Thread
import pickle,time,datetime,os


messages = []
temp = []
os.system("cls")
class Echo(BaseRequestHandler):


    def handle(self):
        self.temp = []
        Thread(target=self.send).start()
        self.username = self.request.recv(8192)
        self.username = self.username.decode()
        print("Got connection from {}:{}".format(self.client_address[0],
                                                 self.client_address[1]))

        while True:
            msg = self.request.recv(8192)
            msg = "[{} {}]: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                               self.username,
                               msg.decode())

            messages.append(msg)
            print(msg)



            if not msg:
                break


    def send(self):

        global temp, messages
        while 1:


            if len(self.temp) != len(messages):

                data_string = pickle.dumps(messages)
                self.request.send(data_string)
                self.temp = [item for item in messages]
if __name__ == "__main__":
    serv = ThreadingTCPServer(("",20000), Echo)
    serv.serve_forever()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket,pickle,os
from threading import Thread
import time
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('localhost',20000))
def receive():

    while True:

        data = s.recv(8192)
        data = pickle.loads(data)
        os.system("cls")
       for item in data:
            print(item)


username = input("Enter your username: ")
Thread(target=receive).start()

s.send(username.encode())
time.sleep(0.1)
while True:

    msg = input(">>")

    if not msg:
       break
    s.send(msg.encode())
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Your indentation within the `while True` loop seem s to be off. The way it is, it will run for ever.

Comment: @Graipher A server is usually supposed to run forever. Do you imply the `break` is not going to have the intended effect?

Comment: @Mast I think he or she was pointing out that the `break` is not inside the loop with the current indentation.  The `def send` seems wrong too, as it doesn't match `def handle`.

Comment: Yes, this is a error on my behalf, my terrible copy and pasting :)

Comment: I have read some places that using pickle over TCP can be dangerous, if this is true, what other methods can i use to send a list over TCP?

Comment: @cheiffeast Please fix the indentation if it isn't already. Indentation is very, very important in Python.

Comment: That was indeed what I meant. And @cheiffeast, please do fix the indentation, otherwise you will get quite boring reviews...

Answer (score 1):

So... `handle()` gets an incoming connection. Great! What's not so great is that it then spawns `self.send` in a thread that will **never die**.

More minorly, I'm not sure why you'd do

```
    self.username = self.request.recv(8192)
    self.username = self.username.decode()
```

instead of just

```
    self.username = self.request.recv(8192).decode()
```